# HTML template for wikipedia

Tags: html, .net, templates, wikipedia

I want to create a wiki website like wikipedia in .Net, but it's seem hard to find an html template like this. Does anyone what template or framework is being used for wikipedia, and where I can download it?

Comment: While this is a old question, it came up while i was browsing for something similar and came across an exact template link at the same time https://html5-templates.com/preview/wikipedia.html

Answer (score 6):

use this https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki

MediaWiki is a free software open source wiki package written in PHP, originally for use on Wikipedia. It is now also used by several other projects of the non-profit Wikimedia Foundation and by many other wikis, including this website, the home of MediaWiki.